# Convert a command from Javascript to Greasmonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am trying to add a character counter to a page, on this page i enter in three values and it returns a large string in the innerHTML of a div with the ID of 'AnswerBoxID', now i want my script to obviously count the number of characters in it to do this i have written

```
var submit=document.getElementsByClassName('Row3');
function countChars(){
    count = document.getElementById('AnswerBoxID').innerHTML.length;
    document.title ="Chars "+count+"/160";
}
```

Which returns a ROUGH approximate of the chars, when i then paste it into an editor or something else that counts chars i get a different result again, counting with this method gets within 5 chars of what other things are reporting (specifically notepad++).

BUT my biggest problem is I have been unable to get countChars() to update
when the value of `document.getElementById('AnswerBoxID').innerHTML` updates, in javascript I overcame that using the following code

```
var submit=document.getElementsByClassName('Row3');
for (i=0; i<submit.length; i++){
    submit[i].firstChild.setAttribute('onclick','countChars()');
}
```

After reading [GM Pitfalls 2](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.232%3a_Event_Handlers) i then modified my approach to the following

```
for (i=0; i<submit.length; i++){
    submit[i].firstChild.addEventListener('click',countChars(),true);
}
```

But it still doesnt work!
And before anyone asks yes I do define the count variable before the function. I don't really mind the mostly accurate length thing I would prefer it to be more precise but I do really want to add onclick elements that run countChars() to the submit buttons.

Comment: Greasemonkey scripts run sandboxed. You can't call `countChars()` from your script using the DOM! You should try a DOM script injection hack.

Comment: thanks man, ill read up on that

Comment: here's a good start: http://wiki.greasespot.net/Content_Script_Injection I have a couple working scripts, I'll test 'em first before posting as an answer, if you don't get an working answer 'til then. :P

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Huh, what's that? Just use [unsafeWindow](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow).

Comment: @hamsolo474: You really should tell us at which page(s) your script runs.

Comment: @Bergi unsafeWindow is not supported in Chrome.

Comment: @Bergi its for work and i need to login, i could copy the page source and dump it in pastebin but only if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greasemonkey scripts run sandboxed. That means, the script runs in the page's `onload` event then is removed. Calling your Greasemonkey script's `countChars()` function when the form is submitted will return an `undefined` error, as your function object is no longer present in the DOM.

Here's my simplified `contentEval` function (based on GM wiki's [Content Script Injection](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Content_Script_Injection)'s function):

```
function contentEval(source) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script.textContent = source;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

You can also set the `text` property instead of `textContent` for compatibility with older IE versions, thanks RogG!

Put that function in your GM script, it will serve to append any function you need to user later to the DOM's head.

Pass your `countChars` function as a parameter to the `contentEval` function:

```
contentEval(function countChars() {
    var count = document.getElementById('AnswerBoxID').textContent.length;
    document.title ='Chars '+count+'/160';
});
```

This way, your `countChars` function will be placed inside a `script` element appended to the document's `head`, which will be accessible after the GM script's execution time ends.

If you want to check a demo of the code above, use a DOM Inspector in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/vpL2k/). It creates a new `script` element which is appended to the  (in JSfiddle's case, the `iframe`'s) document's `head`, meaning it will be accessible whenever you need it.

You could also simply attach the function to the [`unsafeWindow`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow), but you should avoid using `unsafeWindow` unless strictly necessary, and note that `unsafeWindow` is not supported in Google Chrome.

Use this page for reference: http://wiki.greasespot.net/Content_Script_Injection

Also use the [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent) method to get the text content of an element (and its descendants) as noted by RobG.

Comment: I think you are better to set the script's `text` property than its `textContent`, but it may be moot.

Comment: @RobG Yes I had `textContent` as it was in the original Wiki post. I just tested the `text` property and it works too, seeing textContent is only supported in IE9+, `text` seems more appropriate. Thanks for the input. Another quick test shows that `innerHTML` also does the job apparently. =]

Comment: Thanks man i have more or less got it working now, only one problem left now, the character counter only always displays the count of the previous content, so when i first click submit it will show 0/160 and then the second time i click submit (and get a new field value) i get the char count of the previous value

Comment: Also innerHTML does do the job BUT thats what i was getting poor accuracy with before, text doesnt work at all for me and for some reason textContent seems to be producing most accurate results

Comment: Post a new question with your new code and test example in jsfiddle, I can help with the `charcount` function if you need too. =]

Answer (score 2):

You seem to add the event handler wrong.

```
elm.setAttribute('onclick','countChars()');
```

would set an attribute, and eval `'countChars()'` in the global scope when the element is clicked. Yet, Greasemonkey scripts run [sandboxed to their own global object](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Global_object), and your declared function "countChars" is not available to the eval.

```
elm.addEventListener('click',countChars(),true);
```

executes the function immediately and adds the return value as a handler. To make it work, just remove the brackets and pass the function itself. See also [`element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)

Comment: I think this is a much better way than contentEval :-)

Answer (score 1):

In GreaseMonkey, you should be able to use:

```
var count = document.getElementById('AnswerBoxID').textContent.length;
```